# Getting Weird Normals after Importing from Mixamo

Tags: texturing, uv, rigging, normals

File can be found here: https://gofile.io/d/wLt28K

So I took a base mesh from Sketchfab and exported it to mixamo to get a quick rig on it since this is going to be an extremely small part of my project. When I import the FBX back into Blender from Mixamo, the normals or maybe the UVs appear to be a bit wonky, with a clear seam between parts of the mesh. This is visible on the back and in the head vs the rest of the body. The other problem is that I can't take the mesh and shade it smooth. Any help that can be offered on resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated. The original mesh can be found here: https://sketchfab.com/3d-models/free-base-mesh-e4049b5274904bf5ab91001b2bc25eae

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just unplug the normal map from the shader:

[image]

Comment: This was it, thank you!